# Spacing between words ruins URL?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
exports.exec = async (client, message, args) => {
    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.
    if (args.length < 1) {
        return message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 0,
                description: `${message.author} Please input something to be generated into the QR code.`
            }
        });
    }
    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.

    var text = args.join(' ');
    var qr_generator = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=${text}`;
    message.channel.send(qr_generator);
};
```

Hey guys, above is the command, it **works** though, when attempting to add several words, i-e. "**hello world** it catches only the *hello*, after putting a space it breaks. I'm not entirely sure how to allow spaces.

Any help is appreciated.

Example -

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on everything after `data=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As space is unsafe character
use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for url encoding

URL Encoding converts reserved, unsafe, and non-ASCII characters in URLs to a format that is universally accepted and understood by all web browsers and servers

```
 var qr_generator = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%20` that represents a space.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters in URLs are encoded using a format called **percent-encoding**.

A space is represented by `%20`.

**e.g.** `https://example.com/hello%20world/`

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the programming language you are using, but encoding the URL might be helpful. Here's an example in Python:

```py
def encode_url(url):
    encoded = ''
    for special_char in url:
        encoded += '%' + hex(ord(special_char)).lstrip('0x')
    return encoded
```

So `encode_url('Hello World!')` would return `'%48%65%6c%6c%6f%20%57%6f%72%6c%64%21'` which is accepted in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/encodeURIComponent) them!

```js
console.log( encodeURIComponent('hello world!') );
```

Comment: `escape` has been removed from Web Standards.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: Right, [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) should be perfect here